# Generating SSH key (ed25519-sk) with FIDO2 token fails with error "Key enrollment failed: requested feature not supported"

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to generate SSH key using FIDO2 HW token (GoTrust Idem Key, USB-A) connected with command:

```
ssh-keygen -O no-touch-required -t ed25519-sk -vvv
```

and it fails with following error:

```
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
debug3: start_helper: started pid=4683
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: start_helper: starting /usr/lib/ssh/ssh-sk-helper 
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal", device "(null)", application "ssh:", userid "(null)", flags 0x00, challenge len 0
debug1: sshsk_enroll: using random challenge
debug1: sk_probe: 1 device(s) detected
debug1: sk_probe: selecting sk by touch
debug1: ssh_sk_enroll: using device /dev/hidraw0
debug1: ssh_sk_enroll: fido_dev_make_cred: FIDO_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ALGORITHM
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal" failure -2
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Enrollment failed: requested feature not supported
debug1: main: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -59
debug3: reap_helper: pid=4683
Key enrollment failed: requested feature not supported
```

I tried upgrading my system (Manjaro Linux, SSH version `OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022`), but this did not solved it.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/google/OpenSK/issues/90), [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364440/cant-generate-ssh-ed25519-sk-key) and [official manual](https://gotrustid.com/download/idemkey_docs/how_to_use_ssh_with_IdemKey.pdf) (which does not mention `ed25519-sk` keys, only `ecdsa-sk`), but I am unable to create ed25519-sk key. Has anybody found anything, which could help me solve it, or prove me, that I want something impossible?

**Note**: Generation of `ecdsa-sk` was successful (running `ssh-keygen -O no-touch-required -t ecdsa-sk`), so I am using it for now.